# Enabling PUT and DELETE in Apache 2.4.6

Tags: apache-2.4

This isn't for a web server; I just want to set up something simple that will allow me to upload files via HTTP PUT.  I am not an Apache expert, and there's probably something obvious I'm missing.

EDIT:

```
DavLockDB "/var/DavLock/DavLock"
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
    Dav On
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "DAV"
    AuthBasicProvider file
    AuthUserFile /var/www/passwd/passwords
    <Limit GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
        Require user test
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

Test with a bad password first, to confirm authentication works.

```
$ curl --include --upload-file ./uploadTest.txt http://test:bad@*.*.*.*/
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 28 May 2019 17:13:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="DAV"
Content-Length: 381
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>401 Unauthorized</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Unauthorized</h1>
<p>This server could not verify that you
are authorized to access the document
requested.  Either you supplied the wrong
credentials (e.g., bad password), or your
browser doesn't understand how to supply
the credentials required.</p>
</body></html>
```

And now the right password:

```
$ curl --include --upload-file ./uploadTest.txt http://test:test@*.*.*.*/
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Tue, 28 May 2019 17:00:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Content-Length: 216
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /uploadTest.txt
on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

Presumably setting "chmod 777 /var/www/html" wasn't enough?  (This is just a unit test tool for a QA project, not a real server, so I'm not worried about bad practice.)

Comment: AFAIK Just enabling the method in stock Apache httpd does not provide the necessary serverside support to facilitate HTTP PUT operations and actually store the file you're uploading. Either the upload URL needs to be a script that manages the uploads, or  non-standard module such as [mod_dav](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dav.html) is needed.

Comment: Based on HBruijn's advice, I've added WebDAV to my configuration (see above).  Authentication is working, but even with the right password, now I'm getting "403 Forbidden" errors.  GET requests work fine.